# Wordpress show tags belonging to custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, taxonomy

I created a custom post type called "portfolio" and added the tags column in editor using:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'portfolio'  );
```

After I add the tags widget to the sidebar it shows all the tags from all my posts. How can I show tags that belong only to the "portfolio" post type?

Also is there a way to change the default name "Tags" for the portfolio post type to "Portfolio Tags"?

Comment: Why don't you register a new custom taxonomy (non-hierarchial) with [register_taxonomy()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for your portfolio, instead of using the native `post_tag`?

Comment: Yes, explaining ***why*** you want to do this instead of creating a new taxonomy would be helpful to figure out the proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way of achieving that would probably be to create a custom taxonomy. That is also the only way to change the name of your tags to Portfolio Tags.

To do that, you can use register_taxonomy():

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function portfolio_tags_taxononmy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Portfolio Tag',
        'singular_name'              => 'Portfolio Tag',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Portfolio Tags',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Portfolio Tags',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Portfolio Tag',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Portfolio Tag:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Portfolio Tag',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Portfolio Tag',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Portfolio Tag',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Portfolio Tag',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Portfolio Tags with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Portfolio Tags',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Portfolio Tags',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Portfolio Tags',
        'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-tags', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_tags_taxononmy', 0 );
```

Now, you can use 'portfolio-tags' instead of 'post_tag':

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'portfolio-tags', 'portfolio' );
```

To generate your tag cloud, you can use wp_tag_cloud():

```
wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-tags' ) );
```

Comment: By the way: You can use generatewp.com to easily generate the appropriate code: http://generatewp.com/taxonomy/